# How to set default rejected promise behavior for all my Express middlewares?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using promises inside express middleware. I want to use the async/await methods.

```
app.get('/data1',async function(req,res) {
    data = await getData1(); // This line throw an error, 
    res.send(data)
})
app.get('/data2',async function(req,res) {
    data = await getData2(); // This line  throw an error
    res.send(data)
})
```

This makes the browser wait forever.
On the server I see

```
(node:251960) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
```

Now, to fix it for one middleware I'm doing:

```
app.get('/data1',async function (req,res){
    return (async function(){
        data = await  getData1()
    })().catch(() => {
        res.send("You have an error")
    }
})
app.get('/data2',async function (req,res){
    return (async function(){
        data = await  getData2()
    })().catch(() => {
        res.send("You have an error")
    }
})
```

I don't like this repetion. How can I set default error? I have tried for example:

```
app.use(function(error,req,res,next)){
    res.send('You have an error')
}
```

But it didn't work.

**In other words:** How to set default function to be called when Express middlewares returning a rejected promise?

Answer (score 1):

Now I found a way how to do it, I'm still keep the question open for more suggestions

```
app.get("/data1",
    wrap_middleware(async (req, res) => {
        data1=await getData1()
        res.send(data1)
    })
 }
app.get("/data1",
    wrap_middleware(async (req, res) => {
        data2=await getData2()
    })
 }

function wrap_middleware(func) {
    return async (req, res, next) => {
        func(req, res, next).catch(err => {
            console.log(err.message);
            res.send("Error");
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what you should do, yes. You might however want to call `next` with the error to use express' error handling.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the use of sending the same error for different function but I think the handling error code could be write in more readable way (just catch the error and do with them what you want the same way you catch errors in any route middleware):

```
function getData1(){
    return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
        setTimeout(() =>{
            reject(new Error('error has occur!'));
        },2000);
    });
}

router.get('/data1', async (req,res, next) => {
    try{
        const data = await getData1();
        res.send(data);
    }
    catch(ex){
        res.send(ex.message);
      //  next(ex); => sending it to express to handle it
    }
});
```

If you want a global error handling then its not any different from any code you want catch errors globally - you can set a function that take as param , the response object and the async code and create general catch for every async call comes from middleware (which has response object)